# Is there any way to throttle the network bandwidth that an svn checkout does?

Tags: svn, networking

On checking out a very large svn repository I would like to throttle the bandwidth used by an svn client as to not impact a very sensitive network.  Is this configurable within svn?  Is this configurable in some other way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not configurable within SVN.  You can (with pain) handle this by running the SVN connection through a bandwidth-throttled (virtual) router, such as DummyNet on FreeBSD.  You can also route the traffic through an HTTP proxy such as Squid that can limit bandwidth, or use built-in Linux iptables functions (using "tc" for Traffic Control) to limit bandwidth, but this is often not easy to configure/use.

For various (mostly out-of-date) information, see http://lartc.org/, but the lartc mailing list (and archives) may be more informative.  Also see http://www.docum.org/docum.org/

Answer (score 3):

I don't see anything in any of the svn clients.  However, you could write your own proxy service and put a simple throttling class in it.

Consider [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/Bandwidth_throttling.aspx) as a reference or suggest some code to the SO community if you want to attempt.

Answer (score 2):

If you have sophisticated networking on your workstation (like OpenBSD's firewall or Linux's traffic control) then you should configure traffic shaping based on destination network.

Answer (score 1):

If you're in control of the SVN server, and it's running through Apache via mod_dav_svn, a workable solution is to install [mod_bw](http://www.uno-code.com/?q=node/64) or [mod_cband](http://dembol.org/blog/mod_cband/documentation/).

With either solution, you can set a bandwidth limit on the virtual host that's providing the SVN repository.